# Import SDK samples from GITHUB in android

Tags: android, github, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

Hi now am creating application in android studio.For that i use some SDK from Github.before using this into my app i need to check SDK samples.If i import the samples into android studio it shows an dialog box to select build Gradle.Please any one help me to solve this one.

Comment: Most of the SDK in github, has options to include the SDK has dependencies in build.gradle, NO need to import the code

Comment: yes i agree.by adding dependencies in app gradle .but before import it need to check functionalities of SDK in sample.So i tried to import samples of an SDK.

Comment: You can download the sdk sample, add it as module to your app and add library dependency.that will also do it